# Merging polygons

Tags: opengl, computational-geometry, vertex, vertex-array

Is there any fast algorithm to merge polygons together as in the image below?

[image]

Notice that new vertexes are created in the process.

Is there any way to achieve this fast enough as to implement it in a real time system (game engine)?